# Red light for hearing?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Studies have shown that red light @ 650 nm can stimulate the regrowth of hair.  Could it then be used to stimulate Cochlear hair cells and restore hearing??

Comment: This is out of scope for this site. You might ask it on a medical site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about human biology, not about physics.